# Нет необходимости кого-чего / в ком-чём

Tags: грамматика, семантика, падежи

Укажите, пожалуйста, отличие:

> Нет необходимости трёх инструкций

от

> Нет необходимости в трёх инструкциях.

При замене родительного падежа на предложный сохраняется ли семантика в данном контексте? Если да, то полностью или частично?

Answer (score 1):

Слово *необходимость* имеет два значения, в зависимости от которых принято выбирать форму:

1. Неизбежность; то, что нельзя *обходить*; обязательное условие;
2. Крайняя потребность в чем-то; нужда.

В первом случае обычно используется родительный падеж:

*Нельзя недооценивать необходимость кислорода для подавляющего большинства живых существ.*

Во втором случае обычно используется предложный с предлогом *в*:

*Наше предприятие испытывает крайнюю необходимость в квалифицированных кадрах.*

В ваших примерах:

- *Нет необходимости трёх инструкций* — нас ничто не обязывает иметь три инструкции.
- *Нет необходимости в трёх инструкциях* — мы не испытываем потребности в трёх инструкциях.

С практической точки зрения, вы можете толковать это следующим образом:

- если необходимость спущена сверху (*неизбежность*/*обязательность* трёх инструкций обусловлена внешними требованиями), то согласуется родительный падеж;
- если необходимость приходит снизу (*потребность*/*нужда* в трёх инструкциях испытывается изнутри), то тогда согласуется предложный.

Comment: Нет необходимости (обязательности) трёх инструкций - так не говорят по-русски.  Я считаю, что ваш ответ НЕВЕРЕН, хотя не стала об этом сразу говорить. В  ответе вы не используете словарь "Управление в русском языке", а излагаете материал  в соответствии со своим пониманием, не указывая ни одного источника для доказательства.

Comment: "либо на потребность/нужда (тогда согласуется предложный)." А что насчет "потребность размножения для нас имеет первостепенное значение"?

Comment: В нацкорпусе миллионы примеров: потребностью согласования, потребности развития, потребности касания, потребность сопереживания, .... https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=S%2Cgen&sem2=r%3Aabstr+%26+der%3Av&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2

Comment: Понимаете к чему я клоню? К тому что с отглагольными существительными это норма.

Answer (score 1):

1. Для заданного предложения правильным является только один вариант: **Нет необходимости (потребности)  в трех инструкциях.**

Сравнить: Необходимость (обязательность) трех инструкций объясняется их спецификой.

2. Пояснение

Слово «необходимость» имеет **два смысловых оттенка**  (обязательность и потребность), причем управление падежом для них **разное**, о чем указано в словаре: [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=необходимость&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

Управление в русском языке

**НЕОБХОДИМОСТЬ**  1. [**обязательность**] **чего**. Необходимость порядка; [Бельяр] громким голосом стал доказывать необходимость подкреплений (Л. Т.).
2. [**потребность]** **в ком-чём**. Необходимость во враче отпала; Вяткин обладал удивительной способностью появляться там, где в его присутствии ощущалась необходимость (Поп.).

Поэтому выбор падежа **можно проверить** подстановкой нужного значения:

Нет необходимости (**потребности в чём**)  в трех инструкциях.

Нет необходимости (**обязательности чего?)**  трех инструкций.

При сравнении речевых вариантов становится ясно, что верен только первый. Таким образом, делаем вывод, что для конкретного предложения **варианты не являются взимозаменяемыми.**

Comment: Почему _(есть) необходимость порядка_ -- это правильный вариант, а _нет необходимости (трёх) инструкций_ -- это неправильный вариант?

Comment: Если вы используете форму Р.п., то "необходимость" имеет значение "обязательность". "Обязательность порядка"  - правильное речевое сочетание, а "нет обязательности трех инструкций" - это неправильное речевое сочетание.  Определяется это на слух, для носителей речи правильность сочетания слов обычно не представляет особой проблемы, но  в случае затруднения следует обращаться к специальной литературе, например "Словарь грамматической сочетаемости слов русского языка".